# Unity's Android Notification system works on my Xiaomi, but on a Huawei every notification has an "Unknown" status?

Tags: unity, android, mobile

When my app starts I check whether there is a notification or not

- if there isn't I create one via `SendNotification(...)`
- if there is, I check their **status**:

  - `var status = CheckScheduledNotificationStatus(notificationId);`
  - On my **Xiaomi** their status is **Scheduled**, so I update them:

    - `SendNotificationWithExplicitID(...)`
  - But on a **Huwaei** it's always **Unknown**, in that case I create a new:

    - `SendNotification(...)`
    - And replace the old ID in the PlayerPrefs.
    - **But on the next startup it's unknown again.**

Maybe I should use `SendNotificationWithExplicitID(...)` as well when the status is **Unknown** so I can keep the **ID**?

Here is the code:

```
var notification = CreateNotification(jsonWrapper.Name, fireTime, title, text);
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(jsonWrapper.Name))
{
    var notificationId = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(jsonWrapper.Name);
    var status = AndroidNotificationCenter.CheckScheduledNotificationStatus(notificationId);
    if (status == NotificationStatus.Scheduled)
    {
        AndroidNotificationCenter.SendNotificationWithExplicitID(notification, "default", notificationId);
        Logger.Log($"Updated a notification: {jsonWrapper.Name} at {fireTime}.");
    }
    else if (status == NotificationStatus.Unknown)
    {
        var id = AndroidNotificationCenter.SendNotification(notification, "default");
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(jsonWrapper.Name, id);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        Logger.Log($"UnknownStatus | Registered a new notification: {jsonWrapper.Name} at {fireTime}.");
    }
}
else
{
    var id = AndroidNotificationCenter.SendNotification(notification, "default");
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(jsonWrapper.Name, id);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    Logger.Log($"Registered a new notification: {jsonWrapper.Name} at {fireTime}.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to go into the Settings, and enable more permissions. (Don't know which one sadly)

Comment: This answer would be even better if you tried different sets of permissions until you narrowed down which were relevant to the problem, or at least shared the set of permissions you enabled in total so future readers have a starting point to work from.